# Kendo UI treeview append new level

Tags: javascript, jquery, kendo-ui, treeview

Kendo UI init:

```
$('#tree').kendoTreeView({
    select: function(e){
        this.expand(e.node);
    }
});
```

I have first level of tree and want to load other levels by click on node.
As I understood from documentation if use datasource it will load first level too.

So I listen click:

```
$(#tree).on('click', 'li', function(e){

    $.ajax({
        url: 'ajax.php',
        type: 'post',
        dataType: 'json',
        data:  $('#filter').serialize(),
        success: function(data){

            $.map(data, function(val){
                // What to do here?
            });
        }               
    });
});
```

In documentation I find only [insertAfter](http://docs.kendoui.com/api/web/treeview#methods-insertAfter) and [insertBefore](http://docs.kendoui.com/api/web/treeview#methods-insertBefore), but nothing like **insertInto**.

How can I make load new data into `li` as child `ul`, or make datasource start to work from second level?

Comment: Why do not use of-the-shelf mechanism for continue loading new levels of the tree? If you have a HierarchicalDataSource correctly defined it loads and expands each level when you click on it. HierarchicalDataSource *do not* load all tree (by default) but one level at the time so the `transport.read` should properly identify the expanded node and load (and insert into) the data received.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can try the [append](http://docs.kendoui.com/api/web/treeview#methods-append) method. The other option is to configure the data source of the treeview. Then it will automatically load new levels when the user expands a node. You can check the online demo: http://demos.kendoui.com/web/treeview/remote-data.html

Comment: Problem of demo is that all data loads from remote host, but in my case first level already loaded. Append is what I need, could you please tell how to add `id` attribute to `<li>` with `append` method? `{taxt:'test',id:'testID'}` doesn't work.

Comment: The append method won't allow you to set the id. You can do it with jQuery after calling the append method. parentLi.find("li").attr("id", "testId")